# Can I lock an external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, permission

I have two identical hard drives. One is the one I will keep updating frequently, the other will be a backup that I update less often.

In order to avoid confusion, I would like to "Lock" the second hard drive the same way you would lock a folder from its "Info" panel, here:

[image]

However, for drives, this option is not present:

[image]

***Is there a simple, quick, Mac OS native way to make the drive locked to prevent mixing them up?***

I tried to set permission to "Read Only" but it still allowed me to make changes on the drive (like move a folder inside another).

Answer (score -1):

I have a disk image on a drive which is passworded.

Seems to work fine but whether it will suit you...

See https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/183826/how-to-create-an-encrypted-file-container-disk-image-on-a-mac/amp/

Comment: Ah, yes, it would take quite a while and quite some storage space to create this Disk Image and lock it, as opposed to the (absence of) time and efforts brought by the "lock" feature of the Info panel. Thank you nevertheless :)

Comment: Takes very little time - just did the whole disk when I did it.